# Lazy instantiation of property returning null in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I don't understand why my lazy instantiation of my `NSDictionary` is returning `NULL`.

I have seen this method of lazy instantiation several times across many tutorials. What did I do wrong?

```
@interface ViewController () 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary* someItems;
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(NSDictionary*) someItems {

    if (!_someItems) {
        _someItems = @{@"1" : @"A",
                        @"2" : @"B",
                        @"3" : @"C",
                        @"4" : @"D",
                        @"5" : @"E",
                        @"6" : @"F",
                        @"7" : @"G",
                        @"8" : @"H"};
    }

    return _someItems;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Some items %@", [_someItems description]);
}
```

Comment: I have tried `[self.someItems description]` and it still returns null.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are accessing your instance variable `_someItems` directly instead of using its custom getter, where it is lazily initialized.

You should do `[self.someItems description]` to do lazy-initialization.

Comment: I have tried `[self.someItems description]` and it still returns null.

Comment: in that case `[self.someItems description]` cannot return `nil`. maybe you should clean and rebuild your project. also you can try setting a breakpoint in your custom getter to debug

Comment: I have done that as well. I have even created a new project and JUST did the above code. Still `nil`

Comment: my last guess would be a problem with subclassing/inheritance: are you sure this class and its superclasses have one and only one property named `someItems`, right? do you also experience other problems with debugging? your problem might be anything else other than lazy-init. having said that: i run out of suggestions :) good luck

Comment: Side note, but you also don't need to call `description` explicitly. `NSLog()` does it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code in my project. If I print

```
NSLog(@"Some items %@", [self.someItems description]);
```

it works and prints -

```
Some items {
    1 = A;
    2 = B;
    3 = C;
    4 = D;
    5 = E;
    6 = F;
    7 = G;
    8 = H;
}
```

Comment: Exactly. It should work. I don't know why it isn't working for me.